# Possible to set a _ttl at the index level?

Tags: elasticsearch, ttl

In elasticsearch, _ttl value can be set for documents or types; but, can _ttl value be set at the index level? Either for individual indices as they're created or globally for all indices?

I wish to implement a retention policy that deletes indices, not just documents.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to look at the `curator` tool provided by Elasticsearch that provides support for that: https://www.elastic.co/blog/curator-tending-your-time-series-indices

Answer (score 0):

You can use Curator that allow you index operations:

- Delete (by total space consumed or by date)
- Close
- Disable bloom filter cache
- Optimize (Lucene forceMerge)

After installation, you can manage retention period like this:

```
$ curator.py --host my-elasticsearch -d 90
```

That mean you want to keep no more than 90 days of indices.

More details [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/curator-tending-your-time-series-indices).

Regards,
Alain